# Multi-threaded performance std::string

Tags: c++

We are running some code on a project that uses OpenMP and I've run into something strange. I've included parts of some play code that demonstrates what I see.

The tests compare calling a function with a const char* argument with a std::string argument in a multi-threaded loop. The functions essentially do nothing and so have no overhead.

What I do see is a major difference in the time it takes to complete the loops. For the const char* version doing 100,000,000 iterations the code takes 0.075 seconds to complete compared with 5.08 seconds for the std::string version. These tests were done on Ubuntu-10.04-x64 with gcc-4.4.

My question is basically whether this is solely due the dynamic allocation of std::string and why in this case that can't be optimized away since it is const and can't change?

Code below and many thanks for your responses.

Compiled with: g++ -Wall -Wextra -O3 -fopenmp string_args.cpp -o string_args

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <stdint.h>

// For wall time
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <time.h>
#else
#include <sys/time.h>
#endif

namespace
{
  const int64_t g_max_iter = 100000000;
  std::map<const char*, int> g_charIndex = std::map<const char*,int>();
  std::map<std::string, int> g_strIndex = std::map<std::string,int>();

  class Timer
  {
  public:
    Timer()
    {
    #ifdef _WIN32
      m_start = clock();
    #else /* linux & mac */
      gettimeofday(&m_start,0);
    #endif
    }

    float elapsed()
    {
    #ifdef _WIN32
      clock_t now = clock();
      const float retval = float(now - m_start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
      m_start = now;
    #else /* linux & mac */
      timeval now;
      gettimeofday(&now,0);
      const float retval = float(now.tv_sec - m_start.tv_sec) + float((now.tv_usec - m_start.tv_usec)/1E6);
      m_start = now;
    #endif
      return retval;
    }

  private:
    // The type of this variable is different depending on the platform
#ifdef _WIN32
    clock_t
#else
    timeval
#endif
    m_start;   ///< The starting time (implementation dependent format)
  };

}

bool contains_char(const char * id)
{
  if( g_charIndex.empty() ) return false;
  return (g_charIndex.find(id) != g_charIndex.end());
}

bool contains_str(const std::string & name)
{
  if( g_strIndex.empty() ) return false;
  return (g_strIndex.find(name) != g_strIndex.end());
}

void do_serial_char()
{
  int found(0);
  Timer clock;
  for( int64_t i = 0; i < g_max_iter; ++i )
  {
    if( contains_char("pos") )
    {
     ++found;
    }
  }
  std::cout << "Loop time: " << clock.elapsed() << "\n";
  ++found;
}

void do_parallel_char()
{
  int found(0);
  Timer clock;
#pragma omp parallel for
  for( int64_t i = 0; i < g_max_iter; ++i )
  {
    if( contains_char("pos") )
    {
     ++found;
    }
  }
  std::cout << "Loop time: " << clock.elapsed() << "\n";
  ++found;
}

void do_serial_str()
{
  int found(0);
  Timer clock;
  for( int64_t i = 0; i < g_max_iter; ++i )
  {
    if( contains_str("pos") )
    {
     ++found;
    }
  }
  std::cout << "Loop time: " << clock.elapsed() << "\n";
  ++found;
}

void do_parallel_str()
{
  int found(0);
  Timer clock;
#pragma omp parallel for
  for( int64_t i = 0; i < g_max_iter ; ++i )
  {
    if( contains_str("pos") )
    {
     ++found;
    }
  }
  std::cout << "Loop time: " << clock.elapsed() << "\n";
  ++found;
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Starting single-threaded loop using std::string\n";
  do_serial_str();
  std::cout << "\nStarting multi-threaded loop using std::string\n";
  do_parallel_str();

  std::cout << "\nStarting single-threaded loop using char *\n";
  do_serial_char();
  std::cout << "\nStarting multi-threaded loop using const char*\n";
  do_parallel_char();
  }
```

Comment: It'd be interesting to see timings for this without OpenMP. Also the code for contains_str and contains_char as well as compiler flags so we can repeat the experiments ourselves..

Comment: Have you tried both debug and release binaries?

Comment: Not comparing apples to apples. Move the string construction out of the loop to get an equivalent comparison.

Comment: Without OpenMP the std::string version takes about 5.5 seconds, which again is allocation I guess. The reason I didn't pull the string construction out is that this is toy code that I wanted to resemble our real code. In the real version the call to the function that takes the parameter is not obviously inside the loop and so taking the std::string construction out isn't quite as obvious thing to do. In any case i fact this should be pulled out as "pos" has been written in a variety of places. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: For those interested is it possible to attach a file to post or shall i just copy it in (this is my first question :) )?

Comment: @MartynGigg: You can't attach a file; you'll have to paste it in (so exclude irrelevant bits) or upload it elsewhere and link (and hope the other site doesn't leave it as a dead link down the road).

Comment: I've edited the post to include the full toy code and compiler flags. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is basically whether this is solely due the dynamic allocation of std::string and why in this case that can't be optimized away since it is const and can't change?

Yes, it is due to the allocation and copying for std::string on every iteration.

A [sufficiently smart compiler](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SufficientlySmartCompiler) could potentially optimize this, but it is unlikely to happen with current optimizers.  Instead, you can hoist the string yourself:

```
void do_parallel_str()
{
  int found(0);
  Timer clock;
  std::string const str = "pos";  // you can even make it static, if desired
#pragma omp parallel for
  for( int64_t i = 0; i < g_max_iter; ++i )
  {
    if( contains_str(str) )
    {
      ++found;
    }
  }
  //clock.stop();  // Or use something to that affect, so you don't include
  // any of the below expression (such as outputing "Loop time: ") in the timing.
  std::cout << "Loop time: " << clock.elapsed() << "\n";
  ++found;
}
```

Comment: Before the STL I made a COW string class.  I tried to handle the "turn this constant character array into a string" case efficiently, but it was cumbersome and still not as efficient as not creating the string all the time.

Comment: @Omnifarious: The problem is you can't automatically distinguish string literals from "normal" char arrays.  But some string library could let you distinguish that manually, say contains_str(some_string_type::from_literal("pos")).  Imagining a nearly perfect (for this question's purposes) COW string type that allowed this, it would be very close to no overhead, but there would still be some.  I think constexpr in C++0x has the potential to reduce the overhead to zero in this hypothetical case.

Comment: I handled it with a bool constructor argument that defaulted to `false`. You would set it `true` if the string was a literal.

Comment: @Omnifarious: I prefer a factory method to anonymous true values scattered throughout uses, but it's the same result.

Answer (score 2):

Does changing:

```
if( contains_str("pos") )
```

to:

```
static const std::string str = "pos";
if( str )
```

Change things much? My current best guess is that the implicit constructor call for `std::string` every loop would introduce a fair bit of overhead and optimising it away whilst possible is still a sufficiently hard problem I suspect.

Answer (score 1):

`std::string` (in your case temporary) requires dynamic allocation, which is a very slow operation, compared to everything else in your loop. There are also old implementations of standard library that did COW, which also slow in multi-threaded environment. Having said that, there is no reason why compiler cannot optimize temporary string creation and optimize away the whole `contains_str` function call, unless you have some side effects there. Since you didn't provide implementation for that function, it's impossible to say if it could be completely optimized away.

Comment: If we assume the sample is representative, the compiler wouldn't be able to see the function body either, or do any optimizations based on such (it would have to assume the function could use and change global state).

Comment: @Mark, compilers do the whole program optimization for years now. It doesn't need to see the definition in the same TU in order to optimize the call.